# Help needed in getting started with Codepen

Tags: codepen

I just signed up in Codepen, but can't however get anything to work. I have tried Googling the errors but couldn't find any remedy.

The problem: I am getting a persistent `The connection was reset.` error on Chrome, and `Secure Connection Failed`, `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR` on Firefox:

[image]

[image]

I have also tried switching to different internet connections.

Please help.

Comment: This looks like a temporary server-side problem at Codepen. I visited your pen just now (https://codepen.io/leimapapa/pen/KKrxbYx), and it shows up correctly for me. Try again, if the problem persists, try a different browser.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Still the same :/ Tried Chrome, Firefox, Safari...

Comment: I notice how your pen causes lots of requests to the backend server. Maybe you have been blocked by Codepen?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal How do you know that about my computer? In any case, I also signed up with a new email address, and the same issue persists. :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting problems of this nature are off-topic for [webapps.se] but may be on-topic on another [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites)